# bookdown/rmarkdown/knitr: links from PDF to local files and windows/OSX

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

My [`bookdown`](https://bookdown.org/) report `knitted` to `PDF` tries to link to the underlying results like so

```
[This](./somedir/.) directory contains some data.
```

or so

```
[This file](./somedir/specific_data.txt) contains something more specific.
```

On (Arch)`Linux` using `okular` (my devel environment) all of this just works fine (file manager opens for the first, `MIME` type defined application for the second link), but on `MS Windows` and `OSX` Acrobat Reader asks whether to follow that link and after allowing to do so, the only thing that happens is that the dialog window disappears ...

Is what I want generally impossible on those platforms or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks, Joh

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/580) as there are no takers ...

Comment: Have you tried if with `[This file](somedir\specific_data.txt)` you get the opposite, *i.e* if the issue is the platform-dependency of the path separator (`/` vs. `\`)? PS: And what about Acrobat Reader on Linux? Would eliminate one of the unknowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
[This](run:somedirrelativetothedocument/.) directory contains some data.

[This file](run:somedirrelativetothedocument/specific_data.txt) contains something more specific.
```